# Duda con Visual Studio Code y Python

Tags: python, vscode

mi duda es la siguiente, al momento de utilizar por primera vez la función eval() de Python, el IDE me abre automáticamente un archivo nuevo con la leyenda "No se puede cargar el origen "string": Source unavailable.". ¿A qué se puede deber?

Captura del Código
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando lo ejecuto de forma normal, corre bien
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema surge, cuando yo ejecuto el código en modo depuración, al leer la primera linea que contiene el eval(), Visual Studio Code me abre un archivo nuevo en el que me dice el error de String, pero despues ejecuta el código normalmente.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Dónde usas esa función? ¿En un programa? (si es así, ¿cómo lo ejecutas?) ¿En la consola de depuración? ¿En una termina?

Comment: Te edite la publicación original, saludos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como suponía, el error aparece al depurar.

Hay dos formas de depurar "paso a paso": "por procedimientos" (tecla F10) o "por instrucciones" (tecla F11). La diferencia se entiende mejor si la línea en la que está detenida la depuración contiene una llamada a una función:

```
resultado = funcion(datos)
```

Si estando parado en esa línea pulsas F10 ("por procedimientos"), el intérprete ejecutará por completo la llamada a la `funcion()`, pasándole los datos, sin detenerse dentro de ella, y sólo cuando la función haya retornado y tengas ya el `resultado`, se detendrá el depurador, dejándote preparado para la línea siguiente.

Si en cambio, en esa misma línea, pulsas F11 ("por instrucciones"), entonces el depurador ejecutará la llamada a la función, pero se detendrá inmediatamente en la primera instrucción de la misma, mostrándote su código fuente, y permitiéndote continuar la depuración "dentro" de la función.

Si sabes que tu función es correcta, puedes usar F10 para "saltarte" su depuración (aunque se ejecutará y tendrás el resultado). Si en cambio sospechas que la función contiene errores te interesará usar F11 para "entrar" a ejecutarla paso a paso y descubrir dónde falla.

En tu caso lo que tienes es:

```
a = eval("5 + 3 * ( 2 + 2 )")
```

Si pulsas F10, se ejecutará la evaluación de la cadena y tendrás en `a` el resultado (17) sin problemas.

Si en cambio pulsas F11 (que sospecho es lo que has hecho), entonces el depurador intentará "entrar" paso a paso a la función. Ya que `eval()` es lo que se llama un *built-in* (una función incorporada en el propio lenguaje) no tiene código que puedas depurar. Aún así, ya que la misión de `eval()` es "ejecutar" como si fuera código python el contenido de la cadena que le pasas, el depurador intentará ejecutar "paso a paso" esa cadena.

El problema es que en ese momento, cuando intenta mostrarte el código fuente que vas a depurar, debería mostrarte el código contenido en la cadena ("5+3*(2+2)"), pero no le es posible porque el depurador siempre intentará cargar el código desde un archivo fuente, y en este caso el fuente no está en un archivo, sino en un string.

En definitiva, no uses F11 sino F10 sobre esa línea.

### Ampliación

¿Y si la cadena que estás evaluando con `eval()` contuviera llamadas a otras funciones? Considera el caso siguiente:

```
def duplicar(x):
    r = 2*x
    return r

a = eval("duplicar(5 + 3 * ( 2 + 2 ))")
print(a)
```

¿Qué ocurre si estamos parados en la línea con el `eval()` y pulsamos F10 ó F11?

- `F10`. Pues lo dicho, se ejecuta `eval()` completo. La ejecución no se detiene hasta que `eval()` haya terminado. Como consecuencia de `eval()` se ejecutará `duplicar()`, pero eso no lo veremos paso a paso. De una sola vez se ejecuta todo y se detiene en el `print()`, esta vez con `a` igual a 34.
- `F11`. Se entra a ejecutar "paso a paso" la cadena `"duplicar(5 + 3 * ( 2 + 2 ))"`. Inicialmente no verás nada, salvo el mensaje `No se puede cargar el origen "<string>": Source unavailable.`, por la razón ya explicada. El código que está siendo depurado no ha sido leído de un archivo, sino de una cadena.

  Pero si vuelves a pulsar F11, la "primera línea" de esa cadena (que no estamos viendo) se ejecutará, y esa línea es una llamada a `dudplicar()`, por lo que entrarás a la función `duplicar()` para ejecutarla paso a paso. En ese momento podrás volver a ver el fuente, ya que esa función *sí está definida en un fichero*, y podrás ejecutarla por tanto paso a paso y no "a ciegas".

Comment: Perfecto, lo voy a poner en prueba, te agradezco un montón tu ayuda.

Comment: @flacpu He añadido un ejemplo más complejo con más explicaciones.

Comment: Con el ejemplo lo entendí mejor a la depuración por procedimiento y paso a paso, de nuevo, muchas gracias por atender mi consulta.